# Мигает окно Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, окно

Мигает окно.  1 на 2 и бесконечно

**1**
[image: 1]

**2**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема подскажите пожалуйста ?

Comment: Кликните по нему или alt+tab на это окно. Как получит фокус - перестанет мигать, я думаю.

Answer (score 1):

Я удалил все драйвера из раздела Видеоадаптеры. Потом драйвера сами установиться надо 2 раза перезапустить ком. Если не получится то попробуйте 2 раз. У меня с 1 раза не получилось